# Left and Right Sliding webviews in Android

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I got a list view with set of links. When i click on the element of the list view it opens a webview. No i wanna add the sliding functionality onto that by adding Sliding menus/window using this https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/.

But the problem is the SlidingMenu only has one method ie setBehindContentView(). There is no method for setting forward content view.  How can i achieve both left and right sliding in my webview app like Flipboard app.

Answer (score 1):

There is setBehindContentView() and setSecondaryMenu() where the setSecondaryMenu() will set a right side menu.

You also need to set the mode to LEFT_RIGHT via:

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct if it has helped you?